# Turn multivalued function into single valued function

Tags: python, math

[image: example multi valued function]

I was wondering if there is a way, symbolic or numerical if i can basically take all the points at the same x(t) and add the corresponding y(t) values, and turn it into a unique new function in f(x).

I have the values for x(t) and y(t), but i can fit a function and do it symbolically if that is easier.

EDIT: Add more information

Sorry I just actually realized how hoard an abstract and general case could be. And I think I found a crack in my specific case.
So I have a function f(x), and its derivative f'(x). I need to plot f(x) vs f'(x), and add values of f'(x) where there are two or more f(x) values.

Comment: I think you mean turning parametric equations into cartesian form

Comment: Sure, but that is not always possible (as i understand it) when in x lets say the function is not single valued

Comment: changing form is not easy and even not always possible. I _think_ it should be done a case by case study. As it is now your question is a bit "broad" and more mathematically oriented. Could you provide a specific example?

Comment: maybe [this](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/vector/api/classes.html?highlight=parametric#implicitregion) could help

Comment: Based on what you're showing: no. There is no function that can generate all three blue points, as "plain" y=f(x) functions can only yield a single value for `y` given a single value `x`. That said, if you rotate your graph by literally any angle, so that we have three coordinates with _different_ values for `x`, then the answer becomes "yes, there are quite a few ways of fitting a function to those points".

Comment: Can you put the data in a `DataFrame` with three columns for t, x, and y?  Then you could group by x and sum the y values--is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Do you have a formula for x(t) and y(t)? If yes, what is that formula?

Comment: If you can find the two "turning points", the extreme points in the topright and bottomleft, and cut your curve into three segments, then each segment can be reparameterized under the form y=f1(x), y=f2(x), y=f3(x). And then it's easy to combine the three.

Comment: @TMBailey I think that's actually a really good idea. I didn't think about using a dataframe, but i'll give it a try

Comment: It would help a lot if you can give at least one toy example showing desired result as well as starting point.  This could be data tables if you are working with discrete data.  If you are working with continuous functions x(t) and y(t) for real t, then perhaps a chart showing the result you want for a specific input graph would help.